# django admin order of fields and form

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to arrange (readonly) fields above a form and put some info fields below it:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["nbr", "store", "data", "created", "last_change",]
    form = pForm
    ordering = ["nbr", "store", "data", "created", "last_change",]
    readonly_fields = ["nbr", "store", "created", "last_change",]
```

I want to achieve this order:

1. nbr
2. store
3. pForm <-- to edit "data"
4. created -- changed (can I easily put them in one line or do I have to use somehting like: `def hlp(self, obj): return f"{obj.created} - {obj.last_change}2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the fields as you wish using the ModelAdmin.fields option.

Try this:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = ("nbr", "store", "created", "last_change")

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm
```

Comment: thank you. I am aware of this. but how do I put the form on the desired place?

Comment: You can rearrange inside modelform